# Cleaning git branch from no longer relevant commits

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project in my own separate fork (in a separate branch). Over time, I've racked up a fairly large amount of commits. I'd like to push the changes upstream (pull request) but I have many commits that became irrelevant as I was developing. So say I have history like

```
A - B (upstream/master)
     \ 
      C - D - E - E1
               \
                1 - 2 -- 3 - 4 (local)
                     \  /
                       Z
```

Now I'd like to make a pull request from `4` to `B`. There are many commits such as `D` that no longer exist in the files and upstream doesn't need to know about. Consider `A - B - C` where the the file content at `A` is identical to `C`. When making a pull request from `C`, I'd like to first clean up the branch to make it seem like `B` never happened.

How can I do this?

Please don't comment with ‘You should just preserve your whole history, it shows your thinking &c’. I'm asking mostly out of interest.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how to apply only the commits `D - E - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4` on top of `B`?

Comment: In this example, yes. But say `1 - 2` no longer affect any further commits as well: that is, by the time we're at `4`, anything changed in `1 - 2` no longer exists such as would be the case if `3` was a revert commit. Ideally I'd just like to make `1 - 2` disappear.

Comment: I put in a close vote for this question because you can find the solution to rewriting history pretty easily in the many Git docs online, but now I'm having second thoughts, maybe this question is actually helpful to have on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Well, while I accepted an answer already, there might be someone with a better idea for automatically squashing irrelevant comments. The only reason I made the question to begin with was lack of information about what I was looking for – an automated way. I've settled for interactive rebase but I don't think that automatically makes the question useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rebase -i origin/master` will replay your branch history on top of the current `origin/master` and you can `fixup`/`squash` your commits or **delete them entirely** (you just remove the commit lines when the editor pops out). Just see the instructions during the rebase.

Alternatively, you could `reset --hard origin/master` to bring your branch into the same state as `origin/master` and then `cherry-pick` the commits you want.

By the way, when I'm working on a fork, I usually add the official repo: `$ git add remote official https://github.com/rails/rails.git` and when I want to submit the pull request I do a rebase on it: `$ git fetch official` and `$ git rebase official/master`.

Comment: `origin/master` is not quite right, the original poster wants to make a pull request to `upstream/master`.  Since he's using GitHub, `origin/master` probably refers to his own remote fork, not the remote upstream repo that he forked from.

Comment: I ended up doing an interactive rebase after all and squashing a lot of commits making the intermediate ones disappear if irrelevant.

Cupcake, it works if you don't commit on your own master ;)